# Detecting changes across two images

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the change in pixels across two images. 
Visually looking at them, there seem to be too many changes but calculating the distance between pixels gives me around about the same percent change values.

I am trying to calculate the distance here by adding the squared differences for each pixel and its square root which gives me the distance of value at rgb level for each pixel. i.e how much has the pixel value changed (sqrt((img1.r - img2.r)**2+(img1.g - img2.g)**2+(img1.b - img2.b)**2).

Then I am trying to check how many such pixels have changed by a threshold of 10.

I am not able to figure out, why does it show about the same difference in any two pair of images.

Is there a problem in the program or have I been thinking incorrectly

```
import pylab,skimage
import imageio,math,numpy as np


img1 = imageio.imread("029.jpg")
img2 = imageio.imread("028.jpg")
img3 = imageio.imread("030.jpg")
wh = img1.shape[0]*img1.shape[1]
squared_diff = ((img1 - img2)**2)
squared_diff1 = ((img3 - img2)**2)
squared_diff2 = ((img1 - img3)**2)
print float((np.sqrt(squared_diff[:,:,0] + squared_diff[:,:,1] + squared_diff[:,:,2])>10).sum())/wh*100
print float((np.sqrt(squared_diff1[:,:,0] + squared_diff1[:,:,1] + squared_diff1[:,:,2])>10).sum())/wh*100
print float((np.sqrt(squared_diff2[:,:,0] + squared_diff2[:,:,1] + squared_diff2[:,:,2])>10).sum())/wh*100
```

Output :

```
45.2615017361
46.1771918403
46.2858072917
```

For higher thresholds like 20 it gives 0 . np.max gives max distance as 15.x  everytime.

Is there any other way to find a feature like number of pixel changed with a threshold?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: 30.jpg][image: 29.jpg][image: 28.jpg]

Comment: it makes sense to show the same difference...you are substracting img2 on img1 and img3 ,if img1 and img3 have approximately the same value then the difference will be almost the same...try using various images...as for the calculation..i think its fine

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan For any pair of images. How ever you check the differences it results around the same. Even if I try out `squared_diff2 = ((img1 - img3)**2)` or any other image it turns out to be the same. Would that be fine as well?

Comment: that would definetly raise a red flag....but why are applying the threshold on blue channel only while the difference(subtraction) is accross all channels?

Comment: i also think that this measure to see the percentage of change is very flawed(didnt understand what you primary wanted to achieve),calculating the square of the difference will not do you justice because the difference will result in some negative values...when you square them they eventually become positive...however it doesnt answer why you get the same value..what you need to calculate is something like  Intersection over union in percentage.100-100*diff.sum()/image1.sum() you want the percentage of change,if nothing changed,diff.sum()/image1.sum will be equal to 1,(100-100*d.sum/im.sum)=0

Answer (score -1):

The value of :

```
img1 = imageio.imread(".jpg")
```

are rgb value ? i mean are they ranged between 0-255 or between 0 and 1. 
Cause if they where all between 0 and 1 then:

```
((img1 - img2)**2)
```

will have always value below 10 indeed the maximum value of this operations could be only 1 and therefore the maximum value obtained here :

```
np.sqrt(squared_diff[:,:,0] + squared_diff[:,:,1] + squared_diff[:,:,2])
```

could be np.sqrt(3) and that's always minor than 10 and ">10" operator will return an array with all False values

Comment: If r is 0 for img1 and 255 for img2 in case of complete black and white images, then img1 - img2 for each pixel would be sqrt(255*255) i.e 255. 10 would be exceeded in each case. 100% change

Comment: It is an rgb image. Values would range between 0-255.

Comment: Ok , my answer was about the case of 0-1! of course if they range between 0-255 there will be value>10 !

Comment: Didn't know if `imageio.imread()` performs some normalization of the rgb value

Comment: No imageio doesn't normalize the rgb values.

Comment: Have you tried to change the threshold to an higher value, or to confront the same image with itself and see if it returns no change at all?